# ERC-1155 token's metadata content on Polygonscan?

Tags: metadata, matic

Is the Polygonscan explorer able to display the content of the metadata file stored off-chain?

It seems it doesn't do this at the moment. On the other side, Metamask and OpenSea display those.

Am I missing something with the explorer?

I tried going on the explorer's page for a token belonging to an ERC-1155 smart contract, but it doesn't show these details anywhere.